# MySQL infrastructure and PHP $_SESSION handling

Tags: php, mysql, session, foreign-key-relationship

I'm using PHP 5+ and MySQL 5+

I will soon start building a web application for a customer but I would like to ask a few questions regarding infrastructure with you guys before I begin...

I'm building this web application for a HR (Human Resources) company who would like to keep track of customer data. It will have tables for Human Resources(peoples) , Customers, Contat-Persons etc and these will be linked to eachother with relationships. For example, the administrators of the application will say that John will be at customer Doe between X period of time.

Nothing special but here comes the part where I need you to help me think:

The customer I'm doing this for has branch offices around different areas (cities) and each office has a few administrators who will work in my application with only "their" customer data. And there will be people who would work with data for multiple areas.

So, after a succesful sign in they should only be presented with data from the city_id they are connected to.

I could do this by adding the column "city_id" to all my tables and then starting a `$_SESSION['city_id']` 
in the login form, then write my MySQL querys like 
`"SELECT * FROM company WHERE city_id={$_SESSION['city_id']}`
I guess.

But I want it to be easy and flexible and the super administrators should be able to add new cities, and link this to a new customers.

How should I build my database structure? And how should I make the super administrators be able to create new cities and link this to other tables dynamically?

I'm thinking of using X + 2 stucture, where X for example could be table Customer, and the other two are City_list and City_handler. City_list will have all the available cities in it, and City_handler will store who and what is linked to what city. Is this a bad thought?

How should this be implemented in practice if I have for example a database structure who looks like this:

**Customers** 
customer_id 
customer_name 
**City_list** 
city_id 
city_name 
**City_handler**
customer_id 
city_id 
If you could help me link these together with FK (i guess?) and tell me a little bit how to work and what the conserns may be, I would be super grateful as this will be a core function around the entire solution and help me get started!

Answer (score 0):

**users**

id | name

**citys**

id | name

**users_to_citys**

user_id | city_id

Each user can serve any number of cities, the number of cities can be easily changed.

Now you just specify the city for each object and check whether the user has rights to manage them.

some code:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT city_id FROM users_to_citys WHERE user_id = ". (int)$uid);
while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $citys[] = $array['city_id'];
}
$_SESSION['citys'] = $citys;
$_SESSION['citys_syfix'] = ' AND city_id IN('. implode(',',$citys) .') ';
```